# Issue in reading data from <p> tag using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

My webpage shows some data whose value I need to read.
For e.g., webpage shows something like:
Campaign Range: 05/06/2015 - 12/30/2015 
Budget:     $50,00.99

I need to read these values using Selenium Webdriver. The structure is:

```
<div class="inner-widget-container">
        <div class="widget-menu-container" data-bind="attr:{id: internal.controlWidgetMenuId}" id="widget-369148223195225-menu" style="display: none;"></div>
        <div class="widget-data" data-bind="attr:{id: internal.controlWidgetInnerContainerId}, event:{dblclick: api.editSettings}" id="widget-369148223195225-inner" style="left: 0px; right: 0px; top: -5px; bottom: 0px;"><div class="rich-text-widget-content" style="position: absolute; left: 10px; right: 10px; height: 320px; overflow: hidden;"><div class="CustomHTML" style=" color:#000000 ;position: absolute;top: 0;bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;"> <p><span style="font-size: 24pt;">&nbsp;BMW 2015 National Video YouTube&nbsp;<br></span></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>Campaign Date Range:</strong> 05/06/2015 - 12/31/2015&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>Report Date Range:</strong> 10/18/2015 - 10/31/2015&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>Highlights</strong></p>
<p>&lt;User Input&gt;</p> </div></div></div>
</div>
```

Kindly suggest how can I find this Campaign Range element and read its value?

Any help will be really appreciated!!

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following css selector:

```
By.cssSelector("div[class='CustomHTML'] p:nth-child(3)")
```

and use `getText()` to get desired text.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='CustomHTML'] p:nth-child(3)")).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
string readCampaignRange = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='inner-widget-container']/p[3]").getText();
```

For more effective code you can take all

in list and check if its the element you need something like:

```
List<WebElement> p_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='inner-widget-container']/p");

string myElement = p_list[3].getText();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but Ans 1 is giving "NoSuchElement" exception. If I try Ans2, then the string readCampaignRange  is coming as 'Campaign Range' only. I am not able to get the value of Campaign Range i.e. 05/06/2015 - 12/30/2015

Comment: can you provide more html text, you need some id / class name and from it give a full path to the element you need

Comment: I have edited the original ques with more html text.Kindly have a look.

Answer (score 0):

you can extract the text directly via xpath:

first it will find the `p` element that has a `strong` element with the text "campaign". Then get the text of that `p` element

```
String xpathExpression = "//p[./strong[contains(text(), 'Campaign')]]";
String campaignRange = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathExpression)).getText();
```

Comment: Its an invalid xpath. I believe issue is with //p[./strong...]

Comment: ? xpath is perfectly fine ;-) can you provide the error message you get?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//p[./strong[contains(text(), 'Campaign Date Range:')]]/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
  (Session info: chrome=46.0.2490.80)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 42 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html

Comment: ahh ok, I will update the xpath, we need to get rid of the /text() part -> because that does not return an element, sorry for overlooking that;-) - try it again with the shorter xpath